# Home button disable (KEYGUARD_DIALOG) IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, android, android-studio, illegalargumentexception

I'm trying to make custom lock screen, and i need to disable Home Button action.My minSdkVersion : 17 , targetSdkVersion 25

My new onAttachedToWindow():

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG);
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
}
```

My onCreate():

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}
```

Error log:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Window type can not be changed after the window is added.
```

I have tried with onKeyMethod it didn't help:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)) {
            return false;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Is there any method without showing activity as launcher

```
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

Comment: You need to set all windows features, including type, before calling setContextView.  I'm not entirely sure you can make a lock screen anymore-  it was once possible, but as Android got more serious about security its pretty much been removed.